# Looking for a book with two main characters and dragons in the plot

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I'm looking for a book (YA fiction, I think) I read aboooout 5-7 years ago from the library, and now I can't find again. In classic style, I know very little about it, but I do know the following:

• There were two main characters: one male, one female. I think they were about the usual YA Character Age (16-18) but I'm not sure.

• The male main character lives in these underground tunnels, but finds his way to the surface...

• Where the female main character is, in some sort of formal society. I remember it was winter, I think. It was cold, at least. She'd been trained in poison use, I think?

• The book ended with a female relation (I think) or friend of the female main character, strapped into a machine that was supposed to summon a dragon somehow.
There are no dragons appearing in the book prior to that time.

• The cover was dark. I think the title was one word.

• The book was standalone, and not (as far as I know) part of a series.

I tried searching WorldCat, but with little success. Anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean the Dragon Chronicles? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Dragon_Chronicles):

> ***The Last Dragon Chronicles*** is a series of seven novels written by Chris d'Lacey. The books follow a college student, David Rain, as he discovers the existence of living clay dragons in the house he lodges at.

I suppose, the male is David and female is Lucy.

Though unlike your guess, its a 7-part series.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your answer to indicate why you think it fits the OP's criteria?

Comment: Sorry, i just saw dragon summoning and potions being used matching in this one. Hope it helps him. As i had read it a long time back.

Comment: That's okay; there's nothing wrong with a partial answer; it would still be nice to have some of that evidence (quotes from one of the books, for instance) actually in the answer

Comment: Nope, that's not the book. Thank you for taking a shot at it, though.

Comment: One other book i can remem is the Dark Elf Trilogy.
The main protagonist is Drizzt, he lives in underground and finds way to surface. But it doesnt have any dragons
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Elf_Trilogy

Comment: Not Drizzt. This book had only two main characters but their stories are equally balanced; moreover, the dragon doesn't show up until the end and primarily as a sort of... channeling.

Comment: I've read this one. It's set in the real world, with small dragons featuring all the way through, not in a fantasy world with dragons only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is *Dragon Rider* by Cornelia Funke.

I read the book and has 1 dragon and two or three main characters
The dragon is looking for a sacred place where his tribe/group can live peacefully without being disturbed by humans. Then the dragon who's companion is a type of cat/dog (i can't remember) are shocked and must travel with him through a long journey to the sacred place

Comment: Can you expand on why you think this? Quotes from the books, plot summaries, anything?

Comment: That's not it, sorry.

Comment: I've read this one too. Again it's set more or less in the real world, with nothing about a main male character living underground.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually, Funke's book does sort of match the male character living underground, because when introduced, Ben does live as a street kid in some damp dark storage buildings in a ship port. However, the clue about summoning a dragon really doesn't match: dragons are present from start to finish.